# Heroku: images don't show after some time

Tags: django, heroku

I've a Django APP hosted on Heroku.

I upload some images within the admin panel, so the show in my site. First minutes/hours after upload they show fine.

However, after a few hours they don't show anymore. I've to upload them again within the admin panel for them to show correctly.

[image]

When in the HTML when no image appear:

```
<img class="my_image_medium" src="/media/category/Artboard_1_PNG.png" alt="Stickers">
```

HTML with image re-uploaded:

```
<img class="my_image_medium" src="/media/category/Artboard_1_PNG.png" alt="Stickers">
```

Django APP Settings:

```
import os



# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^_67&#r+(c+%pu&n+a%&dmxql^i^_$0f69)mnhf@)zq-rbxe9z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'stickers-gallito-app.herokuapp.com',
                 'stickersgallito.pe', 'www.stickersgallito.pe']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'search_app',
    'cart',
    'stripe',
    'order',
    'crispy_forms',
    'embed_video',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stickers_gallito.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'search_app', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'order', 'templates/'),]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'shop.context_processor.menu_links',
                'shop.context_processor.has_shop',
                # 'cart.context_processor.current_time',
                'cart.context_processor.cart_items_counter'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stickers_gallito.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'd39a83vqn3afdj',
        'USER': 'u9qchlpdl8pbao',
        'PASSWORD': 'pcf1d926adfd169634371480b03c270d7da7b9033c81210482571f1a8d0ad689b',
        'HOST': 'ec2-3-93-140-235.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
        # 'OPTIONS': {
        #     'sslmodule': 'required'
        # }
    }
}


# add this
# import dj_database_url
# db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
# DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')



CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


### Culqui Settings ###


CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = 'pk_test_d4d1nYriXvMV0YKk'

CULQI_SECRET_KEY = 'sk_test_sOlYqSB5PDAkwQuZ'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are storing your uploaded images on the local filesystem. You **cannot** do that in Heroku.

Heroku instances are ephemeral, and do not share filesystems between them. Whenever you deploy, or launch a new instance by scaling up, it will not have any of your uploaded files.

You must store them somewhere more permanent. S3 is a good choice; there are plenty of third-party Django file storage libraries available that will do this for you.

Comment: Hi Daniel, any recommendation in a Django file storage library?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on how to deploy your static files on Amazon S3, which I'd highly recommend: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Comment: Note, it's fine to serve the static files from the filesystem (via whitenoise). The problem is the user-uploaded media files.

Comment: @Sam ty, that tutorial helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is because heroku nodes are not persistent. Meaning everytime your free node shuts down, it actually gets deleted and a new instance gets started when you access your application again.

The solution is actually to use some other hoster to store your media files. Amazon S3 or a simple FTP Server for example.

Check these links for further information:

[Using AWS S3 to Store Static Assets and File Uploads](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)

[Heroku Help: Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)